# Sending data with static time to Graphite

Tags: graphite

I am currently sending logs to Graphite that are updated with timestamps and a value every 30 minutes, however I am also keeping logs that calculate trends in this data for every 30 minute period over each day in the course of a week.

For example, in JSON:

```
{
            "stat_id": "1-0-32",
            "_t": "16:00",
            "value": 26.0,
            "value_count": 4.0,
            "day_type": "Weekday",
            "day": "Monday"
          }
```

would be the average value for 16:00 on a Monday for a specific metric. I would like to be able to graph this trend data on top of the raw data that is already being graphed. I've already used Graphite functions like `averageSeries(timeStack(metric, "7d", x, y))` to try to recreate the trend data but am not confident it represents the trends as accurately and completely.

So I guess the question is can I do this by sending data to Graphite that only changes in value and where the timestamps are static and somehow represents hours in the week?

Comment: I suppose one thing I can do is to give this data arbitrary timestamps that represent some week and then use absolute time ranges to merge over my raw data...

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is adding the trend data as if it were real-time data by applying the time stamps to the current day, making sure not to add future metrics.